# Periodically automatic unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, iis

With unit tests I can test applications if they work properly. But is it possible to check this periodically?

What I want to create is create an application, or service that throws and alert signal when the application breaks.

What I can do is use applications like [Auto IT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to "simulate" user actions on a testing database / server.

But is there an easier and better way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be confusing unit tests, integration tests and monitoring.

Comment: Oops, i will look into intergation testing. To be honest I never used it....

Comment: So what's the actual question here? How to simulate user actions? Or how to run tests? And what do you mean by "periodically"?

Comment: Hello @buxter,  the question is how I can properly monitor my web application(s). I have a IIS logging enabled that generates a xml file on 404,403 and 500.x messages. The "periodically" part is that a system is checking if the application is "healty" like I do with an server. If not it must throw an message to the application owner and system administrator.

Comment: Why not just having a CI with tests running on a schedule?

Comment: @buxter, Good idea did not think aboau that :)